# Visual Studio: Continue after Sanitizer Exception

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, address-sanitizer

I think AddressSanitizer is a good addition to Visual Studio, but it causes problems, let me tell about my case.
E.g. I implemented my custom strlen() function as follow:

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *my_string) 
{
    int n = 0;
    if (my_string == NULL) return 0;
    while (my_string[n] != 0) n++;
    return n;
}
```

This function works well, until the program is built with AddressSanitizer enabled, this will cause an exception when running program under Visual Studio Debugger because the function attempts to read 1 byte out of bound of the param 'my_string', so far, so good, But how could I ignore this exception and continue excecuting program normally ???

Visual Studio behavior currently: if I click 'Continue' in Exception Dialog: it break another time, and another time then exit abnormally.

What I want: Click 'Continue', and Visual Studio knows that I told it "I know this exception, but I will solve it later, now, ignore it and move on". I know, we could disable exception handling of specific type in VS Debugger by using Menu -> Debug -> Windows -> Exceptions Settings, but in my case, I just want to ignore 1 exception upon encountered it, not for specific type.

Comment: @AlexF I know the function is okay, but AddressSanitizer thinks that it's not okay because it attempts to read 1 bytes OOB, so it breaked in with exception, the question is how to ignore the exception on Continue NORMALLY, not about whether the function is okay or not.

Comment: Could you clarify (inside question description) why reading OOB data is ok in your case?

Comment: @yugr that's I'm trying to implment the strlen() function myself, so it must read and test the last '\0' character, which is OOB read.

Comment: The last `\0` character is _not_ an OOB read. If it were OOB read the value of the char would have been undefined. Asan has detected a real error in your code and correctly informed you about it. You should fix it rather than skip and continue.

Comment: @yugr: Sorry, I don't see where the mistake is in the code. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ThomasWeller there is no error in `my_strlen` function but most likely there is a bug in creation of input parameter to the function (which caused Asan report).